# Augmention property of matroid along perfect matching

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matroid-theory

Let M be a matroid of rank k, B a base, X a set of rank rank(X) < k, and P a perfect matching of the complete bipartite graph (X, B).

Is it true that there exists an edge (x, b) of P augmenting X (that is to say, rank(X + b - x) > rank(X))?

This is true for transversal matroids, and it looks true for graphical matroids but I suspect it to be false in the general case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always. Take a graph with three edges: $x_1=e_2;e_1$ and a loop $x_2$. Take $X=\{x_1,x_2\}$, $B=\{e_1,e_2\}$, perfect matching is $x_1-e_1,x_2-e_2$.